# AWS and TLS Authentication

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services

Does anyone know how I can enable TLS Authentication on an application running inside an AWS Ubuntu machine.

To be specific, I have an Ubuntu machine on AWS running Linux Container (LXC) and LXD (a framework on top of LXC that provides REST APIs to access Linux Containers, among other things). I generated certificate and key on the Ubuntu host using LXC command line utility. I then tested whether the certificate works locally by running curl command providing the --cert and --key options to it, and everything works fine. 
I then copied the Certificate over to my local machines (Mac OS X) keyChain and tried accessing the Ubuntu Server (which btw has an open security, allows traffic from everywhere on any port.) It gives me the error : "This server could not prove that it is X.X.X.X . Its security certificate is from ip-X.X.X.X".

I noticed that the certificate has the DNS name value as the private IP address given to the machine by AWS instead of public IP address.

Does any one know how I can access my TLS enabled application inside an AWS Ubuntu machine from outside, public network?

Please let me know if things are not clear and I would be happy to provide more details.

Comment: Please clarify which IP addresses the two instances of X.X.X.X in your question stand for.

Comment: So the X.X.X.X is the "Public IP Address" of the AWS Ubuntu machine, whereas ip-X.X.X.X is the "private IP address" of the AWS Ubuntu Machine

Comment: Thanks.  You are looking for regular TLS authentication, not client authentication - client authentication goes in the other direction.  I edited your question accordingly and will provide an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Within the certificate is a field that specifies what machine name or IP address the certificate should be coming from.  This prevents another site from grabbing the same certificate and presenting it as the other site's certificate.  The issue in this case is that your certificate specifies the AWS internal address, but the client sees the external address of the server.

The solution is simple:  generate a security certificate with a subject alternative name (SAN) that is the external IP address rather than the internal IP address.  External clients will then see the certificate IP address as matching the address they went to.

Comment: Thanks Warren. Unfortunately I do not have the right to change the certificate generation logic.